# Why is RARRAY_LEN not being allocated?

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I'm using the C extension methods to create a new ruby array, but RARRAY_LEN is not getting set.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
long int max = 4;
VALUE rAry;

rAry = rb_ary_new2(max);
printf("allocated: %lu\n", RARRAY_LEN(rAry));
```

output:

```
allocated: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently rb_ary_store(obj, index, val) needs to be used to increment RARRAY_LEN.  It's strange that a method so crucial is basically undocumented.

Comment: It's because the array you created in C was empty - it was just allocated memory for 4 items. It's incremented because you populated it. More details in the answer I posted.

Answer (score 2):

From `array.c` (Ruby 1.8.6):
`#define RARRAY_LEN(s) (RARRAY(s)->len)`

`RARRAY(s)->len` is the same as `Array#length`.

`rb_ary_new2(4)` is not the same as `Array.new(4)`.

```
VALUE
rb_ary_new2(len)
    long len;
{
    return ary_new(rb_cArray, len);
}

VALUE
rb_ary_new()
{
    return rb_ary_new2(ARY_DEFAULT_SIZE);
}
```

`ARY_DEFAULT_SIZE` is defined as `16`.

What is does is just allocate memory for an array - but doesn't populate it. Use it when you know the final size of your array so it doesn't have to be dynamically re-sized.

What you want to use for your intentions are `rb_ary_new3` or `rb_ary_new4`.

From [Programming Ruby: The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html):

> `VALUE rb_ary_new3(long length, ...")`
>   
>   Returns a new `Array` of the given *length* and populated with the remaining arguments.
>
> `VALUE rb_ary_new4(long length, VALUE *values")`
>   
>   Returns a new `Array` of the given *length* and populated with the C array values.

Note that these functions require you to provide a value for each element. So you'd need to do something like: `rAry = rb_ary_new3(4, Qnil, Qnil, Qnil, Qnil)` to replicate `Array.new(4)`. If you provided less arguments you'd get strange behavior in Ruby. (No exceptions - despite the fact you get an invalid object.)